# Ionic 2 - tabs disappear when i push component from side menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Ionic tabs disappear whenever I push a new page/component from side menu navigation.it works fine when i go to tabs child navigation.

Comment: have you used both tab menu and side menu?

Comment: yes i am using both tab menu and side menu.

Comment: Are you use `tabsHideOnSubPages` this property

Comment: For tabs child navigation i mention tabsHideOnSubPages:false property in app.module. it is working great, the issue is when i try to navigate from side menu then tabs navigation got disappear.

Comment: That's also subpages. U can try `this.navCtrl.push()` instead of `this.navCtrl.setRoot()`